# What is the meaning of "from the inside out"?

Tags: phrases

I guess the meaning of "from the inside out" is thoroughly. Is it right?

Here is an example sentence.

That will change you **from the inside out**

Comment: Generally it means "starting from the inside".

Answer (score 2):

When referring to a person, inner can mean the soul or spirit; the body being a shell of lesser importance. So *"That will change you from the inside out"* means that your future actions will change because you are fundamentally a different person. So, likely some significant religious or personal development that focusses on self-knowledge rather than actions is involved.

Answer (score -1):

That will change you from the inside out

the phrase **inside out**  [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inside_out)

Yes, thoroughly, but in the following context: to change something or someone utterly. To change the inside [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Inside+Out) person (inward character, perceptions, or feelings) so the outside [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/outside) person changes too (On or to the outer or external side). Prior external influences are no more.

As in:

> 'He would have to tear himself from the inside out to find the truth.'    'In rehab, they changed me from the inside out.'

Comment: That's not the definition of "*from* the inside out".

Comment: Still not giving the definition of "*from* the inside out".

Comment: @HotLicks  edited again. gave it my best. edit if you desire.